# Collapse rows in treeview-table onLoad (HTML) with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a treeview-table that I used to collapse and expand data, but how can I show collapsed all rows on load? I use this to collapse-expand:

```
 if (tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        } else {
            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();
        }
        return children;
```

This is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vd5BH/79/

Comment: Check my answer and see if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in the end:-

```
  $('.toggle').trigger('click');
```

Based on your current logic you are toggling on the clicked `span.toggle` current state. SO in document ready right at the end just trigger the click event for all the `span.trigger`. This will make all of them collapsed.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPGUx/)